# Using MyISAM table to increment multiple values on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table: cd_biblio which has a list of books. 
 
When I insert a new book from my php page, I want to increment a field ('Ingresso') based on the value 'Class' I inserted. 
For example:
I insert a new book with class 'A', his 'Ingresso' value will be the current max of 'Ingresso' for the class 'A' + 1. 
How can I do this using MyISAM?

Comment: add table schema to question. output of `show create table cd_biblio;`

Answer (score 0):

use prodedures or triggers f.e:

```
delimiter ~
CREATE PROCEDURE AddBook(...)
BEGIN
  DECLARE gIngresso INT DEFAULT 0;
  SELECT Max(Ingresso) INTO gIngresso FROM Table;
  INSERT INTO Table VALUE(... , gIngresso)
END~

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Where should I put this code? The db is already populated, is it ok with this code?

Comment: @Ettore, i don't know structure of your db, so i can't write full code, google stored procedures and triggers, you have 2 options: crate procedure and change everywhere in the project INSERT to the CALL AddBook or write trigger for adding rows in the table.